# Python dlopen/dlfunc/dlsym wrappers

Tags: python, linker, dlopen

Anybody knows if actually exists a wrapper or ported library to access to Unix dynamic linker on Python?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Would [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html) do what you want?

Answer (score 2):

The module is called [dl](http://docs.python.org/library/dl.html):

```
>>> import dl
>>> dl.open("libfoo.so")
<dl.dl object at 0xb7f580c0>
>>> dl.open("libfoo.so").sym('bar')
1400432
```

... though it's nasty and you might want to consider using ctypes or an extension module.

**Edit**

Apparently, dl is deprecated in 2.6 so you'll want to use ctypes which has a better API anyhow.

Comment: deprecation of dl in favor of ctypes confirms that my near-guess of an answer was correct. *phew*.